# ¿Como obtener con Javascript el valor de la propiedades aplicadas a un elemento con CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Tengo un código algo así:

```
.position{
 position:relative
}
```

```
<div class="position" id="position"></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('position').style.position
```

> Resultado es " "

Pero si lo pongo directamente en el `HTML`

```
<div id="position" style="position:absolute"></div>
```

> Resultado es "absolute".

Ya he hecho que se ejecute el `JS` cuando el documento halla cargado con `DOMContentLoaded`

Quisiera saber el porque, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina. +1 por haber explicado tu problema de forma correcta.

Comment: Tienes un error cuando aplicas la clase. No es `clase="position"`, en realidad debes usar `class="position"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Si necesitas obtener los estilos aplicados "*en línea*" a un elemento, puedes usar [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Pero, si necesitas obtener los estilos aplicados con `CSS` y "*en línea*" a un elemento, puedes usar [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('element');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

console.log('Element postion = ', compStyles.getPropertyValue('position'))
console.log('Element z-index = ', compStyles.getPropertyValue('z-index'))
```

```css
.position {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="position" id="element" style="z-index: 1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

sugiero que lo hagas con JQuery ya que facilita mas el proceso de esta forma

```js
function cambiarPosicion(){
if($("#position").css("position") == "relative"){
  $("#position").css("position","absolute");
  $("#position").html("Posicion absoluta");
  $("#position").css("left","200px");
}else{
  $("#position").css("position","relative");
  $("#position").html("Posicion relativa");
  $("#position").css("left","0px");
}
}
```

```css
#position{
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="position">Posicion Relativa</div>

<button onclick="cambiarPosicion()">Cambiar posicion</button>
</body>
</html>
```